# How do I prevent user saving a lead record if lead status is open?

Tags: validation-rule

New to Salesforce, trying to build my experience and knowledge with some basic freelance work, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? See [ask].

Comment: I don't know what formula to use to prevent a user saving a lead record when the status is open.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly elementary Salesforce, I recommend a Validation Rule on the Lead Object. Without further context it's hard to say this be the correct answer in 100% of scenarios but it should cover the vast majority.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_field_validation.htm

Additionally, I recommend taking the Trailhead course if you're entirely new to Salesforce: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/validation_rules